# Does OAuth token audience validation do anything else besides string compare of audience?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` to authenticate OAuth tokens in ASP.NET Core apps. If I disabled the built in audience validation and validated the `aud` claim myself, is there anything besides a string comparison necessary, like checksumming or signature checking?

The specific scenario I have is I have a pure clientside SPA app using msal.js (Azure AD OpenId Connect Workflow V2) talking to a .NET API with a different app registration (therefore different ApplicationId/ClientId/Audidence depending on the layer of abstraction). Even with raw `POST` calls, the v2 Oauth workflow doesn't allow me to use an access token with audience A to talk to Audience B. The V1 doesn't allow me to withou exposing a client secret or a private key in the browser. I'd prefer to let the API accept multiple audiences then share app registrations, until a flow exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet.git), the validation actually performed is only string compare. There does not seem to be any checkums or signature checking.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the audiences found in a <see cref="SecurityToken"/> are valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="audiences">The audiences found in the <see cref="SecurityToken"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="securityToken">The <see cref="SecurityToken"/> being validated.</param>
    /// <param name="validationParameters"><see cref="TokenValidationParameters"/> required for validation.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If 'vaidationParameters' is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If 'audiences' is null and <see cref="TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience"/> is true.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException">If <see cref="TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience"/> is null or whitespace and <see cref="TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException">If none of the 'audiences' matched either <see cref="TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience"/> or one of <see cref="TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences"/>.</exception>
    /// <remarks>An EXACT match is required.</remarks>
    public static void ValidateAudience(IEnumerable<string> audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        if (validationParameters == null)
            throw LogHelper.LogArgumentNullException(nameof(validationParameters));

        if (!validationParameters.ValidateAudience)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.Logger.WriteWarning(LogMessages.IDX10233);
            return;
        }

        if (audiences == null)
            throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException(LogMessages.IDX10207) { InvalidAudience = null });

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validationParameters.ValidAudience) && (validationParameters.ValidAudiences == null))
            throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException(LogMessages.IDX10208) { InvalidAudience = Utility.SerializeAsSingleCommaDelimitedString(audiences) });

        foreach (string audience in audiences)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(audience))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (validationParameters.ValidAudiences != null)
            {
                foreach (string str in validationParameters.ValidAudiences)
                {
                    if (string.Equals(audience, str, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        IdentityModelEventSource.Logger.WriteInformation(LogMessages.IDX10234, audience);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validationParameters.ValidAudience))
            {
                if (string.Equals(audience, validationParameters.ValidAudience, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    IdentityModelEventSource.Logger.WriteInformation(LogMessages.IDX10234, audience);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(
            new SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LogMessages.IDX10214, Utility.SerializeAsSingleCommaDelimitedString(audiences), (validationParameters.ValidAudience ?? "null"), Utility.SerializeAsSingleCommaDelimitedString(validationParameters.ValidAudiences)))
            {    InvalidAudience = Utility.SerializeAsSingleCommaDelimitedString(audiences) });
    }
```